# What is the number of different compounds formed from the monochlorination of cis-1,2-dimethyl cyclopentane?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, isomers, cis-trans-isomerism

I encountered this question in the Black Book of Organic Chemistry by Ashish Mishra while preparing for a college entrance exam.
According to the answer key the answer is 12. I have only managed to draw 11 possible structures.
If someone could help me find out the 12th structure it would be greatly appreciated.
[image: The structures I have drawn]

 In this the 1st, 2nd, 5th, and 6th structures are optically active, giving a total of $7+4 =11$ compounds.
PS: I used [this](https://www.rcsb.org/chemical-sketch) to draw these structures. If there is more preferable way to upload structures let me know and I will update them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 7th structure is also optically active. (1*S*,2*R*)-1-(Chloromethyl)-2-methylcyclopentane is different from (1*R*,2*S*)-1-(chloromethyl)-2-methylcyclopentane.

[image: (1S,2R)-1-(chloromethyl)-2-methylcyclopentane]    [image: (1R,2S)-1-(chloromethyl)-2-methylcyclopentane]

Comment: The molecule (1S,2R) exists here. But the molecule (1R,2S) is not produced here.

Comment: @Maurice I believe both will form depending on which methyl group is chlorinated, is the answer not correct?

Comment: Yes, Grimm. Sorry ! It is correct. I had not thought about this possibility. Thank you.